# Xpath - match buttons and links

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Consider xpath for matching all buttons containing certain text:

```
const xpath = "//button[contains(., 'Some text')]";
```

How can I also match links in the same expression?

The following will match all selectors, but I only want buttons and links.

```
const xpath = "//*[contains(., 'Some text')]";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
const xpath = "//*[(self::button or self::a) and contains(., 'Some text')]";
```

another

```
const xpath = "(//button|//a)[contains(., 'Some text')]";
```

Comment: FWIW, it's useful to keep the existence of the `self::` axis in mind, it can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps.

```
const xpath_expression = "(//button|//a[@href])[contains(., 'Some text')]";
```